# Prove $E(R_n(\alpha),R_n(\theta)^n)<\epsilon/3$ from $E\big(R_n(\alpha),R_n(\alpha+\beta)\big)=|1-\exp(i\beta/2)|$

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, universal-gates

[image: mmm]

where $E(U,V)=\max_{|\psi\rangle}||(U-V)|\psi\rangle ||=||U-V||$ is the error when $V$ is implemented instead of $U$. See [page 196, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang.](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)

I have performed calculations for the exercise

$$
E\big(R_n(\alpha),R_n(\alpha+\beta)\big)=|(R_n(\alpha)-R_n(\alpha+\beta))|\phi\rangle|=|(R_n(\alpha)-(R_n(\alpha)R_n(\beta))|\phi\rangle|=\Big|R_n(\alpha)\big[1-R_n(\beta)\big]|\phi\rangle\Big|=\sqrt{\langle\phi|\big[1-R_n(\beta)\big]^\dagger R_n^\dagger(\alpha)R_n(\alpha)\big[1-R_n(\beta)\big]|\phi\rangle}\\
=\sqrt{\langle\phi|\big[1-R_n^\dagger(\beta)\big] \big[1-R_n(\beta)\big]|\phi\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle\phi|\big[1-R_n(-\beta)\big] \big[1-R_n(\beta)\big]|\phi\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle\phi|\big[1-R_n(-\beta)-R_n(\beta)+1\big]|\phi\rangle}=\sqrt{2-2\cos(\beta/2)}=|1-\exp(i\beta/2)|.
$$

Now, how do we prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $n$ such that $E(R_n(\alpha),R_n(\theta)^n)<\epsilon/3$ from Eq. $(4.77)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof consists in connecting together two arguments. The first, covered by the exercise, reduces the problem of approximating the rotation gate $R_\hat{n}(\alpha)$ to the problem of approximating the rotation angle $\alpha$. The second, described in the quoted text from Nielsen & Chuang, shows that one can achieve arbitrarily fine approximations of all angles using a rotation by an irrational multiple of $\pi$.

### Reducing gate approximation to angle approximation

From $(4.77)$ we have

$$
\lim_{\beta\to 0}E(R_\hat{n}(\alpha), R_\hat{n}(\alpha+\beta))=\lim_{\beta\to 0}|1 -\exp(i\beta/2)| = 0.
$$

In other words, for any sequence of angles $\gamma_k$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\gamma_k=\alpha$, we have

$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}E(R_\hat{n}(\alpha), R_\hat{n}(\gamma_k)) = 0.
$$

This means that if we can apply a rotation around $\hat{n}$ by a angle that approximates the rotation angle $\alpha$ to arbitrary accuracy then we can approximate $R_\hat{n}(\alpha)$ to arbitrarily small error $E$.

### Achieving arbitrarily fine approximations of all angles

Now, as shown in the quoted paragraph from Nielsen & Chuang, the set

$$
\Theta=\{\theta_k\,|\,\theta_k=(k\theta)\mod{2\pi}\},
$$

of angles of rotations around $\hat{n}$ attainable by $R_\hat{n}(\theta)^k$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, fills up the interval $[0, 2\pi)$ in the sense that for any rotation angle $\alpha$ and any desired accuracy $\delta>0$ there exists $\tilde\theta\in\Theta$ such that $|\alpha - \tilde\theta|<\delta$. In other words, the set of attainable angles $\Theta$ contains *arbitrarily fine approximations of all angles*. In particular, $\Theta$ contains $\theta^*$ that approximates $\alpha$ to whatever accuracy is needed for $E(R_\hat{n}(\alpha), R_\hat{n}(\theta)^n)<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.

### Connecting the arguments

The connection between the two parts is as follows. The first argument proves the implication that if we can approximate the rotation angle $\alpha$ arbitrarily well then we can approximate $R_\hat{n}(\alpha)$ to arbitrarily small error $E$. The second argument establishes the premise for that implication, namely that we can indeed approximate the rotation angle $\alpha$ arbitrarily well using repeated applications of $R_\hat{n}(\theta)$, as long as $\theta$ is an irrational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: It can be proved that there are distinct $j$ and $k$ in the range $1, . . . , N$ such
that $|θ_k−θ_j|≤2π/N<δ$. Assuming $k>j$ we will get $|θ_k−θ_j|=|θ_{k-j}|<\delta$. How do I make sense of "sequence $θ_{l(k−j)}$ fills up the interval $[0, 2π)$ as l is varied, so that adjacent members of the sequence are no more than $δ$ apart" ?

Comment: How do you ay that "angles of rotations around $\hat{n}$ attainable by $R_\hat{n}(θ)^k$ for $k∈Z$, fills up the interval $[0,2π)$ in the sense that for any rotation angle $α$ and any desired accuracy $δ>0$ there exists $\tilde{θ}∈Θ$ such that $|α−\tilde{θ}|<δ$ " ?

Comment: So the text before your quote shows that the sequence $\theta_i$ contains a non-zero element (namely, $\theta_{k-j}$) whose absolute value is less than $\delta$. Then multiples of this element (i.e. elements of the form $\theta_{l(k-j)}=l(k-j)\theta \mod 2\pi = l\theta_{k-j}\mod 2\pi$) are less than $\delta$ apart and so end up filling the interval $[0, 2\pi)$ with density at least one element every $\delta$. Finally, since $\delta$ is arbitrarily small, we end up with $[0, 2\pi)$ being filled in the sense I described.

Comment: I think it makes sense now, except that where does precisely $\epsilon/3$ comes in the picture ?

Comment: $\epsilon/3$ and $\delta$ are connected by the first part "Reducing gate approximation to angle approximation". Essentially, since we can approximate any angle $\alpha$ with arbitrary accuracy $\delta$ then we can execute $R_\hat{n}(\alpha)$ with arbitrary accuracy by choosing $\delta$ to be so small that $E(R_\hat{n}(\alpha), R_\hat{n}(\theta)^n)$ is less than $\epsilon/3$. This is possible because $\lim_{\gamma\to \alpha}E(R_\hat{n}(\alpha), R_\hat{n}(\gamma))=0$.

Comment: fine, but is there any reason why we take $\epsilon/3$ instead we could just choose $\epsilon$ with the same reasoning ?

Comment: Definitely. They make it a third to get a nice whole $\epsilon$ later in inequality $(4.81)$. The $3$ comes from the fact that any single-qubit unitary can be decomposed into three rotations, see $(4.80)$.

Comment: It is not part of the original post but, could you please also comment on Eq. 4.79 which is $E(R_\hat{m}(α),R_\hat{m}(\theta)^n)<\epsilon/3$ ?. I can see that $E(R_\hat{m}(α),R_\hat{m}(\alpha+\beta))=|1−exp(iβ/2)|=E(R_\hat{n}(α),R_\hat{n}(\alpha+\beta))$ and $\hat{m}$ is a unit vector in the direction of $(cosπ/8,−sinπ/8,cosπ/8)$, and $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector in the direction of $(cosπ/8,sinπ/8,cosπ/8)$ and $E(R_\hat{n}(α),R_\hat{n}(\theta)^n)<\epsilon/3$.